# Obtendo valor inserido em campo texto asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma `GridView` e em uma das colunas possuo um campo `textbox` onde insiro valores neles.

Gostaria de saber como obtenho os valores digitados dos campos, já fiz o seguinte:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= gvTeste.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string variavel = gvTeste.Rows[i].Cells[8].Text
}
```

Porém sempre está me retornando vazio, como se nada estivesse preenchido na célula 8 que é onde inseri o valor.

Comment: voce pode colocar mais trecho do codigo? no meu teste funciona com .Value.ToString() mas tem que ver como você está construindo esse grid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você terá que utilizar um evento de DataBound para recuperar os valores, semelhante a isto.

```
protected void gvTeste_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
      var variavel = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("seu campo txt");
}
```

Com isto você pegará todos os valores do campo informado no FindControl.

Comment: deu certo, fiz assim TextBox txtQtde = (TextBox)gvTeste.Rows[i].Cells[8].FindControl("txtTeste"); nao precisei colocar em um DataBound

Comment: Bacana Arthur, bom saber que também da certo desta forma.